# Why does the compiler require the class qualifier on the return type of an already class-qualified member function definition?

Tags: c++, function-declaration

I'm a little unsure of the verbiage to describe this problem, but take this example:

**Foo.h**

```
namespace sample {

  class Foo {
    public:
      enum Bar {
        kValue1,
        kValue2,
      }

      Bar SomeMethod(Bar some_value);
  } 
}  // namespace sample
```

**Foo.cc**

```
namespace sample {

  Bar Foo::SomeMethod(Bar some_value) { // compiler complains here
    if (some_value == Bar::kValue1) {
      return Bar::kValue2; // but not here
    } else {
      return Bar::kValue1;
    }
  }
}  // namespace sample
```

The compiler complains about the return type in the definition saying:

> error: unknown type name 'Bar'

Why is it that giving the definition of `SomeMethod` the qualification `Foo::SomeMethod` does not extend that same qualification to the return type of `Bar` but does extend the qualification to all the other uses of `Bar` in this method definition?

Comment: Short answer - because such is language grammar.

Comment: These kind of *why* questions are hard to answer besides a "That's how the language is designed".

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Instead of "why is the language this way" I took it to mean "what is different about these two locations that makes one syntax work and not the other" but you have a valid point.

Comment: If I recall correctly 98 required scope resolution for the argument in this case `Foo::SomeMethod(Foo::Bar some_value)` (as per James answer), later versions does not.

Comment: Maybe a little bit of both. :-) I knew the question was a bit heavy in the "why is language" department, but I also couldn't find an answer on the internet so I thought it was still worth it.

Answer (score 4):

```
  Bar Foo::SomeMethod               (Bar some_value)
//^^^ Here is "outside" the class    ^^^ Here is "inside" the class
```

Since `Bar` is defined within the class it's required to use the `Foo::` prefix to access it, unless you're inside the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

It's a name lookup issue. Generally, you don't get to see inside of `Foo` automatically until you are in the parameter list or the function body:

```
namespace sample {

  class Foo {

    public:

      enum Bar {
        kValue1,
        kValue2,
      };

      Bar SomeMethod(Bar some_value);
  }; 

  Foo::Bar Foo::SomeMethod(Bar some_value) {
    if (some_value == Bar::kValue1) {
      return Bar::kValue2;
    } else {
      return Bar::kValue1;
    }
  }
} //namespace sample

int main() {}
```